# Thresholding in Theano

Tags: theano

Is there a way to threshold the values in a Theano tensor? For instance, if `v = t.vector()`, I would like to create another tensor `w` which contains the same values as `v`, except that the ones that exceed a certain threshold `T` are replaced by `T` itself:

```
v = [1, 2, 3, 100, 200, 300]
T = 100
w = [1, 2, 3, 100, 100, 100]
```

More generally, what is there a standard framework to create your own operations on tensors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is code that do that. Use the clip function.

```
import theano
v = theano.tensor.vector()
f = theano.function([v], theano.tensor.clip(v, 0, 100))
f([1, 2, 3, 100, 200, 300])
# array([   1.,    2.,    3.,  100.,  100.,  100.])
```

If you you don't want a min you can use a switch:

```
import theano
v = theano.tensor.vector()
f = theano.function([v], theano.tensor.clip(v, 0, 100))
f([1, 2, 3, 100, 200, 300])
# array([   1.,    2.,    3.,  100.,  100.,  100.])
f = theano.function([v], theano.tensor.switch(v<100, v, 100))
f([1, 2, 3, 100, 200, 300])
# array([   1.,    2.,    3.,  100.,  100.,  100.])
```